# Call ant from batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, ant

I want to call ant from a batch file.

```
@echo off 
cmd.exe /k cd /d E:\work\CRM 
call ant
```

It's not working. Nothing is happening; neither showing any error nor nothing... How do I call ant?

I need to execute `ant compile` command from batch file from the current location `E:\work\CRM`.

Also I set the environment variables for ant:

ANT_HOME
JAVA_HOME

Comment: Does your `PATH` variable include the folder containing `ant.bat`?

Comment: What is this `cms.exe` doing?

Comment: Yes I got it ..no need to write cmd.exe..and ya my PATH variable include ant.bat

Answer (score 1):

1. Get rid of `cmd.exe /k` since you're already in a batch file context
2. Add `-d` after `ant` to show debugging info